# how to select or deselect column from GUI

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

```
 <v-select
      v-model="selectedHeaders"
      :items="$con.col"
      label="Select Columns"
      :menu-props="{ maxHeight: '200' }"
      multiple
      outlined
      return-object
    >
      <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
        <v-chip v-if="index < 2">
          <span>{{ item.text }}</span>
        </v-chip>
        <span
          v-if="index === 2"
          class="grey--text caption"
        >(+{{ selectedHeaders.length - 2 }} others)</span>
      </template>
    </v-select>
  </v-flex>
  <v-data-table

    :headers="showHeaders"
    :items="desserts"
  >
computed:{
 showHeaders() {
  return this.$con.col.map(c =>
    this.headersMap[c] || { text: this.$options.filters.capitalize(c), value: 'attributes.' + c }

  )
 }
},
```

con.col contain the columns name and this is python file ...if i remove columns list from con file of python then some of the default columns name will show on table ...i didn't get any clue from where the default columns name fetch and show into the table ...i have headersMap but and headersMap contain the object of array ....i before  have tried one more possibility but i did not get any appropriate output ..below are the code which i have also tried before

```
<v-select
      v-model="selectedHeaders"
      :items="headers"
      label="Select Columns"
      :menu-props="{ maxHeight: '200' }"
      multiple
      outlined
      return-object
    >
<v-data-table
    :headers="showHeaders"
    :items="desserts"
  >
headers: [],
  headersMap: {
    name: { text: 'Dessert (100g serving)', value: 'name' },
    calories: { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
    fat: { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
    carbs: { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
    protein: { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein', sortable: false },
    iron: {text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron'}
  },
created () {
this.headers = Object.values(this.headersMap);
this.selectedHeaders = this.headers;
},
computed: {
//Done to get the ordered headers
showHeaders () {
  return this.headers.filter(s => this.selectedHeaders.includes(s));
}
 }
```

**other possibility**

```
<v-select
      v-model="selectedHeaders"
      :items="headers"
      label="Select Columns"
      :menu-props="{ maxHeight: '200' }"
      multiple
      outlined
      return-object
    >
<v-data-table
    v-model="selected"
    :headers="showHeaders"
    :items="desserts"
>

showHeaders() {
  return this.headers.map(c =>
    this.selectedHeaders[c] || { text: this.$options.filters.capitalize(c), value: 'attributes.' + c }
 )
 },
created () {
this.headers =  this.$con.col.map(c =>this.$options.filters.capitalize(c))
this.selectedHeaders = this.headers
}
```

i have tried many more possibility but not getting any result. **con.col contains the column name id i remove col list from con file then the table get default value of column name  **

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why are you reading from a python file?

Comment: yup ...actually web app fetch database from python file